# make parent menu item bold when visiting child page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which gives the menu item a class of 'current'. I then style that with `font-weight:Bold;`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var loc = window.location.href;
    $("ul a").each(function() {
        if (loc.indexOf($(this).attr("href")) != -1) {
            $(this).addClass("current");
        }
    });
});
```

If the user is on a page which is within the sub menu `ul li a` how do i add a class called `Bold` to the parent UL/LI at the root level?

here is the structure, if i am on Q&Z Group then About us needs to be bold. - http://jsfiddle.net/zZQy3/

Comment: What is your HTML structure for the menu? Are you trying to apply the 'Bold' class to the parent element to `$('ul a')` as in your function above?

Comment: here is the structure, if i am on Q&Z Group then About us needs to be bold. - http://jsfiddle.net/zZQy3/

Comment: @MarkWalters, i am trying to add the class to `ul.sf-menu li ul li a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var loc = window.location.href;
$("ul a").each(function() {
    if (loc.indexOf($(this).attr("href")) != -1) {
        $(this).addClass("current");
        $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').addClass("Bold");
    }
});
```

Comment: This will only bold the immediate parent, which has already added the class of current to. The bold should be applied to the next parent li element.

Comment: here is the structure, if i am on Q&Z Group then About us needs to be bold. - http://jsfiddle.net/zZQy3/

Answer (score 1):

if you have the current node as a jquery variable, you can access its parent by using `parent`.  So, you could use `$(this).parent().addClass(...);`

If you wanted to, rather than using javascript for this logic, you could use the [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

```
$('ul li:has(a[href=' + window.location.href + '])').addclass(...);
```

This is looking for any LI that has a descendant with an href matching the current url by way of the [Has](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and [Attribute Equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selectors.

Comment: This will only bold the immediate parent, which has already added the class of current to.  The bold should be applied to the next parent li element.

Comment: If you want the parent's parent as the cale_b suggests, use `$(this).parent().parent().addclass()` or `$('ul li:has(li a[href=' + window.location.href + '])')`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/):

```
$(this).parent("li").parent("li").addClass("bold");
```

Note there are two parents above - this is because your a element is within an li, which is not what you want bold.  You want the li parent of THAT to be bold.

Comment: But `parent()` only travels to the first parent, not a grandparent. And an `li` can't be an immediate child of an `li`.